# To find a row in dataset with a primary key value

Tags: vb.net, dataset

Help , return dr gives me nothing. I know I am missing something. I am new with this dataset datatable. Please give me some direction. Thank you

Do I have to initialize the datatable? how ? I thought the datatable is filled when you initialized the database

```
ds as new dsPart
```

My table adapter inside dataset query is as follows. The dataset name is dsPart

```
SELECT     AttributeValue, Value, Expr2
FROM   Vehicle
```

AttributeValue is set as primary Key

[image: Vehicle]

```
Public Function getVehicleRow(ByVal iRideVehicle As Integer) As dsPart.VehicleRow
   Dim ds As New dsPart
   If iRideVehicle = 0 Then Return Nothing
   Dim dr As dsPart.VehicleRow = ds.Vehicle.FindByAttributeValue(iRideVehicle)
   Return dr
End Function
```

The value of irideVehicle when I call this function is 2132. 
which exists.
The content of vehicle table is:
+-----------------+--------+-------------+
| AttributeValue  | Value  |    Expr2    |
+-----------------+--------+-------------+
|           2132  | Honda  | new_vehicle |
|            3214 | Toyota | new_vehicle |
|            3546 | Subaru | new_vehicle |
+-----------------+--------+-------------+

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You do not fill any data into your dataset - so you won't find anything when you call `FindByAttributeValue(..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I think **forgot to load data** from your dataStorage into your dataSet.

```
Public Function getVehicleRow(ByVal iRideVehicle As Integer) As dsPart.VehicleRow
    Dim ds As New dsPart
    Dim da as new VehicleTableAdapter() ' Created TableAdapter
    da.Fill(ds.Vehicle)  ' Load data into dataTable
    If iRideVehicle = 0 Then Return Nothing
    Dim dr As dsPart.VehicleRow = ds.Vehicle.FindByAttributeValue(iRideVehicle)
    Return dr
End Function
```

I am used to write c# code, so please excuse minor syntax errors.